# Login with one email id, pay with other using Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a website where I need the user to log in. After logging in the user needs to make a payment and then he/she can check the rest of the website.

Now the problem that I'm facing is:

**Suppose I log in with an account : 'a@gmail.com',
password : ******.**

After that I get redirected to Paypal,
and there I log in using different credentials which are:

**email : 'abc@gmail.com', password: ******.**

All the process works perfectly till here. And my payment is even succesful.
But the issue that I face is:

```
How will I manage the Payment Status in my DB?
```

The log that I receive from paypal is:

```
    Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 30.00
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payer_id] => 9CABB2SHMA4MW
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 23:31:25 Nov 08, 2015 PST
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [first_name] => abc
    [mc_fee] => 1.47
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [business] =>asadd@asd.com
    [quantity] => 1
    [verify_sign] => AQx90ScEndGDbMxp11maXxRe9dElAiIDxUQmtFtv8ASyfExv42B1SAra
    [payer_email] => abc@gmail.com
    [txn_id] => 54J45833C00682608
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => Prajapat
    [receiver_email] => asadd@asd.com
    [payment_fee] => 1.47
    [receiver_id] => 8DMUTQEYCK35S
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] => Membership Cost
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] => Abc
    [residence_country] => IN
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [payment_gross] => 30.00
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [ipn_track_id] => aae79d1f40a3a
)
```

So, please suggest to me whether there is any solution for it.
Or at the time of registration, do I need to mention to users that you need to use only that id which is registered with paypal?

Please help me, I'm new to paypal and I have no knowledge about it.

Comment: I have passed the user_id in session and then used it as well in my Update query. But it doesn't work there.

Comment: I use this query :
$email = $_POST["payer_email"]; // received from paypal log
//$email = $_SESSION["m_email"]; // session id

If I use $_SESSION["m_email"], the query doesn't works.

$update_user = "UPDATE member SET transaction_id='".$trasaction_id."',payment_status='".$status_pay."' where email='".$email."'";

Comment: @Burki, since its paypal sucesspage, I can not run it on browser and check the result

Comment: I have access to response, I did mentioned the paypal response as well.

Comment: I think i start to understand your problem... You surely have a field where you can send something like an invoice ID that you generate once per user, that is sent to paypal, and will be part of the response. This can then be used to identify your user.

Comment: I do not have any invoice id generated in paypal response array

Comment: Downvoters can comment as well if there is an issue, that is only way I can improve my question. As I have already achieved my answer, so why downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after searching a lot, I got the solution. I just hope that it helps others as well if they face the same issue.

[This url](http://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php) solved my issue. **Add a custom variable to your form and then retrieve it on your success payment page**.

**Example :**

```
<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='<?php echo $email; ?>'/>
```

and then retrieve it as :

```
 $_POST['custom']
```

I hope it solves others issue as well.